# how to pull data that is older than 6 months on Crystal Report XI?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a field titled `COMPLTDATE` that is a `DATETIME`; however when I write,within select expert, `{ORDERSEC.COMPLTDATE} >= currentdate - 6 months` I receive an error.

How should I write it so that it pulls all the data from the last six months ?

Comment: The error is "THE REMAINING TEXT DOES NOT APPEAR TO BE PART OF THE FORMULA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ORDERSEC.COMPLTDATE} >= DateAdd ('m',-6 ,currentdate)
```

Comment: glad it worked although your description (older than 6 months) indicates you needed {ORDERSEC.COMPLTDATE} < DateAdd ('m',-6 ,currentdate) ... I surmised from your example though that what you needed was the code I gave you.. have a great day!